# Project runs fine on xcode but not with command flutter run

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

When I run with vscode by the ommand `flutter run -v`,
the log outputs like below:

```
executing: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl spawn 7FD2A92B-06D4-421D-BC1D-4D3BE8C4FF3F log stream --style json --predicate eventType = logEvent AND
processImagePath ENDSWITH "Runner" AND (senderImagePath ENDSWITH "/Flutter" OR senderImagePath ENDSWITH "/libswiftCore.dylib" OR processImageUUID == senderImageUUID) AND
NOT(eventMessage CONTAINS ": could not find icon for representation -> com.apple.") AND NOT(eventMessage BEGINSWITH "assertion failed: ") AND NOT(eventMessage CONTAINS "
libxpc.dylib ")
```

But when I run with xcode, everything is fine.
The flutter doctor show no problems, and I can also run other projects fine.
I've tried delete the ios folder under project and enable ios again.

I can imagine it's some pod dependency broken down which cause the problem, but can't understand why can I run it on xcode?

Comment: Try deleting your ios folder, and generating it again with "flutter create .". It seems like there is a path issue with your ios folder.

Comment: @nifesi deleting ios folder and re-generate it is not working. But some how delete the whole project and pull it down from git fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix the problem (well, it's not actually a fix because I don't know why and how the problem happens and disappear...) by delete the whole project and pull the exactly same project down from my VCS again.

I will not mark this as an answer, because it's a solution, but it answers nothing...